# Ordering with Group Concat with Union not coming properly

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to sortout the result as i want it.

The query :

```
SELECT b.bid,REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(f.val), ',' , '')
FROM boxes as b
JOIN boxgroupstype as g ON (b.bgid = g.bgid AND g.btid =3)
JOIN pages as p ON (p.pid = b.pid AND p.qid = '1')
LEFT JOIN formboxverifychar as f ON (f.bid = b.bid AND f.fid = 66)
WHERE val IS NOT NULL AND vid !=0
GROUP BY varname
UNION
SELECT b.bid,b.label
FROM boxes as b
JOIN boxgroupstype as g ON (b.bgid = g.bgid AND g.btid =1)
JOIN pages as p ON (p.pid = b.pid AND p.qid = '1' or p.qid = '2')
LEFT JOIN formboxverifychar as f ON (f.bid = b.bid AND f.fid = 66)
WHERE val IS NOT NULL AND vid !=0
ORDER BY bid asc
```

so the ordering is not coming according to BID in the upper values in which g.btid =3.

The result :

> bid   REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(f.val), ',' , '')
>     1 They are not useful
>     5 They are useful
>     7 Not at all
>     12    A little
>     15    Not at all
>     19    AYNTHON
>     43    HO
>     68    Yes
>     71    TAJLAIYPNAEG
>     95    35
>     98    Yes
>     100   HINESCE
>     123   Male

it should be

> 19 ANTHONY
>      71 PETALING JAYA
>     100 CHINESE

If anybody can help,i would appreciate it much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem myself. Thanks for help friends.

SELECT b.bid,

REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(f.val ORDER BY b.bid), ',' , '')

FROM boxes as b

JOIN boxgroupstype as g ON (b.bgid = g.bgid AND g.btid =3)

JOIN pages as p ON (p.pid = b.pid AND p.qid = '1')

LEFT JOIN formboxverifychar as f ON (f.bid = b.bid AND f.fid = 66)

WHERE val IS NOT NULL AND vid !=0

GROUP BY varname

UNION

SELECT b.bid,b.label

FROM boxes as b

JOIN boxgroupstype as g ON (b.bgid = g.bgid AND g.btid =1)

JOIN pages as p ON (p.pid = b.pid AND p.qid = '1' or p.qid = '2')

LEFT JOIN formboxverifychar as f ON (f.bid = b.bid AND f.fid = 66)

WHERE val IS NOT NULL AND vid !=0

ORDER BY bid asc

Comment: what you did actually?

Comment: vickrant i used order by clause in group concat REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(f.val ORDER BY b.bid), ',' , '')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.bid,REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(f.val), ',' , '') FROM boxes as b JOIN boxgroupstype as g ON (b.bgid = g.bgid AND g.btid =3) JOIN pages as p ON (p.pid = b.pid AND p.qid = '1') LEFT JOIN formboxverifychar as f ON (f.bid = b.bid AND f.fid = 66) WHERE val IS NOT NULL AND vid !=0 GROUP BY varname UNION SELECT b.bid,b.label FROM boxes as b JOIN boxgroupstype as g ON (b.bgid = g.bgid AND g.btid =1) JOIN pages as p ON (p.pid = b.pid AND p.qid = '1' or p.qid = '2') LEFT JOIN formboxverifychar as f ON (f.bid = b.bid AND f.fid = 66) WHERE val IS NOT NULL AND vid !=0 ORDER BY f.bid asc
```